# How to get Ubuntu Server installed from Ubuntu Minimal?

Tags: 12.04, installation, server, customization, ubuntu-minimal

Once I install Ubuntu minimal, then I have option to customize it the way I want.

I can either use it as such with the terminal mode,
Make it ubuntu desktop by `apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` 
Make it kubuntu by `apt-get install kubuntu-desktop` 
Make it Lubuntu by `apt-get install lubuntu-desktop` 
and so on....

One can see a difference with the Ubuntu server version, that during installation it gives option to select

- SSH Server
- Tomcat Server
- LAMP
- DNS Server , etc

Now I am looking for a way or a command something like `apt-get install ubuntu-server`

 so that I may **install ubuntu-minimal** and then proceed with the further process of 
 **making it server** in one go.

I don't want to install individual components (like components of LAMP or DNS) one by one. I am looking for an automated way similar to the one present in Ubuntu server distribution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That functionality is provided by `tasksel` (unsurprisingly, it's in the `tasksel` package):

```
sudo apt-get install tasksel
sudo tasksel
```

this will present you with a menu of options, such as:

```
 [*] OpenSSH server
 [ ] DNS server
 [ ] LAMP server
 [*] Mail server
 [ ] Openstack
 [ ] PostgreSQL database
 [*] Print server
```

You should then be able to select the ones you want, and tasksel will handle the package installation.

Comment: And how can I replace the kernel of Ubuntu Minimal with a kernel optimized for server environment. Or is it that the Ubuntu minimal contains a kernel optimized for server?

Comment: As of 12.04, the server and desktop kernels have been merged. If you `apt-get install linux-image-server`, you'll find that you have the `-generic` kernel flavour, which works great on servers too.